# Collaboration edit for spreadsheet in zk

Tags: java, excel, tomcat, spreadsheet, zk

I want to implement collaboration edit for my spreadsheet means one spreadsheet should accessed by all users.
How can i do this with zk and apache tomcat server.
I did not find collaboration edit using any language.
Do i need to set use any global variables but how can we use application variables.

I need some documentation.

Comment: you can find all the documentation you need on ZK's site. Search about server push, Event queues etc. and implement it on zk's spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this one by setting the scope Application level to the loaded book.

```
loadedBook.setShareScope(EventQueues.APPLICATION);
```

And maintained a static list to store the loaded books.
Whenever user loads a book in the browser, we must check whether this book is available in list if it is available then give this same book reference to the user, if not available then store into the list.
Make sure to remove the books which does not have any users.